# run os.system commands on a new terminal- Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-os

I am running a program which allows me to run terminal commands through my Python code which takes input from the user through the command line. This is the part of the code where I open Google-Chrome

```
import sys
import os 
os.system("google-chrome") #I have Ubuntu 16.04
```

It opens the browser but the problem is that the terminal on which my python code is running becomes the same as the one where Chrome is running which means that I cannot give further input to my Python code. To solve this problem I need the Chrome to run as a process on a different terminal. I tried using `subprocess.call("google-chrome", shell=True)` but it did not open it on a new terminal.

How do I make the process run on a different terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can this solve your problem?

```
os.system('gnome-terminal -x chromium-browser')
```

Comment: This one worked. It opened a new terminal and then launched the browser. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use subprocess.popen("command")

Basically, run the subprocess in the background. & is a shell feature. Use popen instead

Comment: No even this did not work. It still opened in the same terminal