# Run os.system commands in new terminal - Python 3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am running a program which runs terminal codes based on the input recieved by the user on my Raspberry Pi. I want the process to run on a different terminal which is opened by my python code. 
For this on my Ubuntu machine I did

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -x google-chrome") #if i wanted to open chrome
```

But this is not an option on raspbian stretch. I want to know how I can perform similar functions on my raspberry pi

I had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344490/run-os-system-commands-on-a-new-terminal-python-3). Refer to it to get a better understanding of what I am asking

I have Python 3.5.3 on the Raspberry Pi model 2 B running Raspbian Stretch

Comment: What do you mean by "run on a different terminal"? Are you bothered by the output of Chrome in Python's terminal? Or do you want that the Python code continues running side-by-side with Chrome?

Comment: I need the python code running side by side. because when I open chrome(or any other application) it starts on the same terminal as the python code,which prevents me from giving further input to the code

Comment: I think it is not working in Raspberry Pi because there is no `gnome-terminal` installed. You can try replace it with `os.system("LXTerminal -x google-chrome")`. I never try this since I don't use GUI on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I tried doing "lxterminal -x" but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds you do not necessarily want to spawn a new terminal emulator to run a process from, but just want that the process runs side-by-side with your Python code. You can spawn new processes in a more flexible way than `os.system` with the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("google-chrome", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
# Python code continues executing as soon as the process is spawned
print("Hello, World!")
```

The `stdout` and `stderr` arguments state that the output should be discarded (i.e. redirected to `/dev/null`).

Note that by default `Popen` does not use the shell to run your command. If you want to emulate the behaviour of `os.system` more closely, use `shell=True` as an argument to `Popen`. As with `os.system` this can have security implications!

Comment: It worked, thanks. Though i needed to add  `shell=True` in the Popen